# Calculate sales of products that sold this year but not the year before

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to calculate the sum of NetSales for the products that had sales this year (2019) but NOT sales last year (2018).

This is what I'm trying (and a million variations more similar to this):

```
NetSales CY Not LY = 
VAR ThisYear= 2019
VAR YearBefore= 2018
VAR TabelaThisYear = SUMMARIZE(FILTER(SUMMARIZE('Facts';Facts[ArticleNo];Facts[InvoiceDate];Facts[NetSalesCurr]);YEAR('Facts'[InvoiceDate])=ThisYear && Facts[NetSalesCurr]>0);Facts[ArticleNo])
VAR TabelaYearBefore = SUMMARIZE(FILTER(SUMMARIZE('Facts';Facts[ArticleNo];Facts[InvoiceDate];Facts[NetSalesCurr]);YEAR('Facts'[InvoiceDate])=YearBefore && Facts[NetSalesCurr]>0);Facts[ArticleNo])
VAR ProdutosOnlyThisYear = EXCEPT(TabelaThisYear;TabelaYearBefore)
RETURN
CALCULATE(SUM(Facts[NetSalesCurr]);ProdutosOnlyThisYear)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following approach, where we don't hardcode the years:

```
NetSales CY Not LY=
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Facts[NetSalesCurr]),
    FILTER(
        VALUES(Facts[ArticleNo]),
        CALCULATE(
            COUNTROWS(Facts),
            PREVIOUSYEAR(Calendar[Date])
        ) = 0
    )
)
```

Let's break it down:

1. The inner `FILTER` function iterates through `VALUES(Facts[ArticleNo])` - that is all ArticleNo's that have sales in the currently selected period.
2. For every one of those ArticleNo's, we calculate the number of rows on the fact table for the previous year. `CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Facts), PREVIOUSYEAR(Facts[InvoiceDate]))`
3. We keep only those ArticleNo's where this number is `= 0`.
4. The list of ArticleNo's returned from `FILTER` is then used in the outer `CALCULATE` statement, so that we only get the sum of NetSales for articles that did not have any sales in the previous year.

For more information, please see the [New and returning customers-pattern](https://www.daxpatterns.com/new-and-returning-customers/).

Comment: Thanks, it is returning the same value of my experssion (ie: returns the sales of this year regardless of there were any sales last year)

Comment: Ok - what does your data model look like? Do you only have a single table (Facts), or are there more tables / relationships involved?

Comment: It has a sinlge facts table (and a calendar table related to it). The facts table contains the invoice date, article no and net sales.

Comment: Ok - is the Calendar table related to the InvoiceDate column?

Comment: Yes, exactly it is

Comment: The thing is in your point 3 above: if there are no sales of articles the year before, there are also no rows, because there's no "Articles" table in this model.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my question to account for that. The problem with the initial solution was that it didn't remove the existing date filter off of the calendar table, so you were filtering by current year on the calendar table, while simultaneously filtering previous year on just the [InvoiceDate] column on the fact table. You will have to update the measure again if you decide to add an Article dimension later on.

Comment: Regarding point 3: That doesn't matter, as `VALUES(Facts[ArticleNo])` constructs a "temporary" table of ArticleNo's

Comment: This is brilliant: using COUNTROWS = 0 as a way to check there are no rows. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the dax formula like at the below , if you have a calendar table  ;

```
this year = CALCULATE ( SUM[measure];DATEADD(CALENDAR[DATE]),0,YEAR)
last year = CALCULATE ( SUM[measure];DATEADD(CALENDAR[DATE]),-1,YEAR)
```